# What is the fastest way to extract an ISO?

Tags: mount, iso

Currently I'm mounting an ISO to a (readonly) directory (using `mount -o loop` command) and then copying the contents to another normal directory. This takes lot of time as the ISO is large. Is this the only way to do so, or is there some alternative?

Comment: You can have a look at my solution: http://superuser.com/a/1180728/541106

Comment: This not a bad way as the ISO is mounted in the RAM of the system. Extracting with a tools should take the same times.

Answer (score 82):

you can do this by 7zip software:

`sudo apt-get install p7zip-full`

`7z x iso_file.iso`

on Fedora:

`7za x iso_file.iso`

Comment: Worked for me with a Windows 8.1 ISO, for which (in Gnome) neither Nautilus nor Archive Manager were able to show the contents.

Comment: Watch out, "7za x" wont work, only "7z x". Thanks!

Comment: 7za works on fedora, 7z doesn't

Comment: As per [this](https://www.tecmint.com/extract-files-from-iso-files-linux/#comment-869523), `7z` will not extract all the necessary files.

Comment: 7z only supports extraction of Joliet and maximal file size in output will be 64

Comment: It breaks executable bit permissions.

Comment: @Hi-Angel I um, ISO-9660 doesn't even know executable bits. Neither does RockRidge, pretty certain Joliet doesn't introduce them either… so, where exactly would these executable bits actually come from?

Comment: @MarcusMüller it seems like you're right. Although, for some reason I gave an upvote to the two answers about `bsdtar` and `isoinfo`, but skipped this one. So apparently back when I left the comment, the other two answers worked for me, but not this one. Idk what to think about it, can't remember what ISO I've been working with either way.

Comment: And if you need to extract it to a specific directory (which is more often the case), use `7z x <iso-file> -o<extracted-files-dir>` (yes, that's right, no space between the o switch and the directory name, 7zip is weird like that)

Answer (score 10):

`bsdtar` (part of the portable [libarchive](http://www.libarchive.org/)) can parse [*lots* of file formats](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/LibarchiveFormats).  This is handy for those whose fingers are very familiar with tar's options (`bsdtar xfp foo.iso` to extract, `bsdtar tf yoyoma.rpm` to just inspect the contents).

There's also a bsdcpio for those who are familiar with `cpio`'s usage.

Many linux distros now include bsdtar, bsdcpio and libarchive (often as separate packages although it all comes from the libarchive code).

Answer (score 3):

Why not use:

```
isoinfo -R -X
```

to extract all files or

```
isoinfo -R -X -find find-options
```

to extract files controlled by the find options?

Comment: Note that it assumes the `isoinfo` from schily's `cdrtools`. That won't work with the one found on Debian (from `cdrkit` a Debian [fork](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-announce/2006/09/msg00002.html) of `cdrtools` (for licensing reasons AFAICT)).

Comment: Correct, Debian created a fork on May 2004 and did never make any useful progress since then. All enhancements in the original code since than was ignored and this was a lot: more than 60% of the current code in the cdrtools project is from past 2004. In other words more than 50% of the features of a recent original cdrtools is missing in the Debian fork.

Comment: BTW: the Debian fork was created in May 2004, the name cdrkit was used after I asked Debian in September 2006 not to use the original name anymore for a fork with more than 100 Debian specific bugs. Given that all distros that asked a specialized lawyer ship the original cdrtools, I cannot see a proof for a license issue.

Comment: If have to confess I can't say I understand the license issue.

Comment: As I carefully follow all requirements from the licenses (I checked this with several lawyers), I cannot see a license issue. Given the fact that Debian claimed a license issue long before the licenses have been changed, I suspect a "red herring" here. To continue with my time-line from above: Debian claimed a license issue from a non existing change in Autumn 2005, but the license change happened on May 15 2006 in order to defend against the attacks from Eduard Bloch and Jörg Jaspert.

Comment: `isoinfo` (cdrtools -- arch linux) does not work for me. I'm working on Stronghold Crusaders cd image in ISO, and the filenames (at least) are not correct.

Comment: Apparently there is one more implementation of `isoinfo`, in Ubuntu's `genisoimage`, which doesn't support `-X` option. So many `isoinfo`s there, wow…

Answer (score 2):

Mounting the image, or using 7zip as already answered are probably the only two solutions. Try them and check if one is faster than the other.

If you really need something more fast, you should probably look in a different direction: instead of changing software, try to use different disks: one for the source image and one for the target directory. Or, try to avoid copying these files and just keep them in the iso image.

Comment: FYI: using `mount -o loop` and `rsync -a /mnt/iso /root/iso` is copying at ~100MB/s from an internal SATA HDD to an Internal SATA SSD.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to extract only some files instead of the whole content, try `mc` aka MidnightCommander in the shell. It's also neat to look into `.zip/tar.gz/bz2` with.

Answer (score 2):

[uniso](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uniso/) is a Python script that leverages [isoinfo](http://cdrecord.org/private/cdrecord.html) to extract the contents from an ISO stream.  It requires [pythoric](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pythoric/).  It's a bit hacky, but it gets the job done.

I'm the author of uniso and pythoric.

Answer (score 1):

For those who use Thunar file manager on linux and want easy and fast solution:

1. Open thunar --> Edit --> Configure custom actions...
2. Create new item:

   - Name: Extract ISO here
   - Description: Extracts ISO file
   - Command: `xfce4-terminal -e "7z x %f"`
3. Open tab **Appearance Conditions**

   - Prefix: `*.iso`
   - Select **only** `Other files` checkbox
4. Save it and you are ready to extract using right click.

> Note that this trick uses and depends on **xfce4-terminal** and **p7zip** packages. If you are using different archive manager or terminal - replace commands accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I have benchmarked suggested utilities for fastest:

```
FILE=some_file.iso
DIR="./unpacked"

# time 7z x $FILE -o$DIR # see note below
# real    0m0,656s

time xorriso -osirrox on -indev $FILE -extract / $DIR
# real    0m5,528s

mkdir $DIR
time bsdtar xp -C $DIR -f $FILE
# real    0m5,376s

# mkdir $DIR; cd $DIR
# time isoinfo -R -X -i ../$FILE # see note below
# real    0m0,446s
```

They were tested against 780M file at nvme ssd.
So I would stick with 7z, because of synopsis convinience and fast speed.

Edit: I was hurry about 7z. 7z and isoinfo extracts files, but they are corrupted. That's why they worked such fast I think. I was extracting an AppImage file. Then bsdtar seems the best.

Comment: I have commented them out, but left in place for others to be able to easily use their arguments. Also maybe it is a good idea to try with other iso image (i.e. not an AppImage).

Answer (score 1):

Use `file-roller` in Linux and click "Extract" when the popup window comes.

Example:

```
file-roller items.iso
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `genisoimage`. It has all you need to handle ISOs. After you install it you'll also be able to use `mc` to view ISO content.

Comment: Just read through the manpage for this.  Couldn't find any options for extracting the contents of an existing ISO.